# TwitterA API Login Page not showing using Rg.Plugins PopupPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, twitter-oauth, xamarin.auth

Hi I am having a problem displaying the LoginPage for the TwitterApi using Xamarin Auth with a PopupPage using Rg.Plugins.

This is the error:

`Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7f8b3fa8fa00>  on <RgPopupPlatformRenderer: 0x7f8b4089f860> which is already presenting <Rg_Plugins_Popup_IOS_Renderers_PopupPageRenderer: 0x7f8b40943120>`

It is working smoothly on the android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two methods are not compatible - they both try to show the modal controller upon the same controller at the same time.

The worst thing is that as Twitter displays its dialog as a modal controller what you want to achieve (show it in your own pop-up) is impossible even on the native platform, so even if you somehow succeeded in persuading Rg.Plugins to change their code to fix the crash what you wanted to achieve wouldn't work, the app just wouldn't crash.

Comment: thanks! Do you have any suggestion to display the login on IOS with a popup or anything else?

Comment: According to the description that you have provided, Twitter completely handles the process of presentation so there is nothing you can do about it unless it has some other API that would work differently.